# Python: A curious case of Index out of Bounds

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a code to find peaks in a time-series and I want it to plot the local baselines too. At the moment I am using a test time-series built from two cosinusoids.

The code goes as this, where p_times are the times of the center of the peaks:

```
step = 0.1  
time = np.arange(0, 10.1, step)

#Does stuff to find peaks

p_times = [0.9, 1., 1.1, 1.9, 2., 2.1, 2.9, 3., 3.1, 3.9, 4., 4.1, 4.9, 5., 5.1, 5.9, 6., 6.1, 6.9, 7., 7.1, 7.9, 8., 8.1, 8.9, 9., 9.1]

idx = np.array([np.where(time == x)[0][0] for x in p_times])
```

The last instruction should give an array with the indices of the elements of time corresponding to the peaks, but instead I get:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

What makes the case curious is that changing the cosinusoids parameters to what appears to be some "lucky" values, the positions of peaks change as well, and the code works:

```
p_times = [0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5, 5., 5.5, 6., 6.5, 7., 7.5, 8., 8.5, 9., 9.5]
# result: idx = [ 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90 95]
```

UPDATE: Using again the "unlucky" time-series, I have this array of peak times:

```
p_times =  [0.3, 1.8, 1.9, 2., 2.1, 2.2, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4., 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5.8, 5.9, 6., 6.1, 6.2, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8., 8.1, 8.2, 8.3]
```

And the instruction :

```
idx_c = np.array([np.where(np.isclose(time, x))[0][0] for x in p_times])
```

fails again with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4c7f86bac90c> in <module>()
     53 #Baseline extremes (x,y), left and right
     54 #idx_c = np.array([np.where(time == x)[0][0] for x in O[:,0]])  #Cannot manage to vectorize this
---> 55 idx_c = np.array([np.where(np.isclose(time, x))[0][0] for x in p_times])
     56 print("idx_c = ", idx_c)
     57 idx_l = np.array(idx_c - k)  #Left extreme is at index of center (peak) minus k positions.

<ipython-input-1-4c7f86bac90c> in <listcomp>(.0)
     53 #Baseline extremes (x,y), left and right
     54 #idx_c = np.array([np.where(time == x)[0][0] for x in O[:,0]])  #Cannot manage to vectorize this
---> 55 idx_c = np.array([np.where(np.isclose(time, x))[0][0] for x in p_times])
     56 print("idx_c = ", idx_c)
     57 idx_l = np.array(idx_c - k)  #Left extreme is at index of center (peak) minus k positions.

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Actually, if you `print([np.where(time == x) for x in p_times])` you will see that there are some values with no match, and you get `(array([], dtype=int64),),`

Comment: Yes @roganjosh, I noticed that but I'm not sure what to do of it. My point is, how can I make this code work?

Comment: I think this is a floating point issue. `idx_c = np.array([np.where(np.isclose(time, x))[0][0] for x in p_times])` will work

Comment: What I don't get is why it doesn't compare equal if you convert `p_times` to an array and both have `float64` precision, but Python is happy that `1.9 == 1.9`, and the first and second elements of `a = np.array([1.9, 1.9], dtype=np.float64)` compare equal.

Comment: I tried using `np.isclose`, but it returns the same error message.

Comment: Please edit in to the question your attempt with `isclose` because I cannot reproduce

Comment: The only way I'm able to recreate your issue is if I set the `time = np.arange(0, 10.1, step, dtype=np.float16)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary problem with your approach is that you're comparing floating-point values exactly. This is almost always a very bad idea due to rounding errors, demonstrated in this infamous example:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
False
```

Note that numpy doubles and native python doubles are fundamentally similar (I'm not sure about the dependence of sizes depending on architecture in either case, but you probably get my point).

So firstly you should always use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)/[`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) for comparing floats for equality. Secondly, which is the reason I'm posting a full answer: you don't have to use a list comprehension, you can do what you want in a single numpy broadcasting call to `isclose`:

```
>>> idx, data_idx = np.isclose(time[:,None], p_times).nonzero()
>>> idx
array([ 9, 10, 11, 19, 20, 21, 29, 30, 31, 39, 40, 41, 49, 50, 51, 59, 60,
       61, 69, 70, 71, 79, 80, 81, 89, 90, 91])
```

What happens here is that the `time` array is converted to a 2d column array by injecting a trailing singleton dimension, and a matrix of bools is constructed by pairing every `time` point to every `p_times` point. The final call to `nonzero()` returns the indices of the `True` values: the first output `idx` contains the indices you're looking for.

This method is also safer, in that it won't throw an exception if a peak doesn't have a matching time. Instead you'll have fewer `idx` values than `p_times` points. In this case you'd be able to use `data_idx` to locate the indices of the peaks that were actually found:

```
>>> data_idx
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])
```

Comment: Thanks @Andras Deak, that works great - and I was looking for a way to avoid list comprehension with its `for` loop.